Unbounded Double Complex with Diagonal Boundary
I am new to spectral sequences and am not very familiar with convergence results once we lose boundedness.
Suppose we have a differential cochain complex $X^n$ of $R$-modules with differential $D$, where $R$ is some ring. I can refine this to a double complex $X^{a, b}$ with vertical differential $D_v$ and horizontal differential $D_h$. This double complex is not bounded with respect either $a$ or $b$, but it has a diagonal boundary - by which I mean $X^{a, b}=0$ for $a+b<0$.
The horizontal cohomology can be computed in the examples I am looking at, and is given by
$$
H_{D_h} (X^{a, b}) \simeq X^{a, b} \delta_{a+b=0}.
$$
so our subsequent page of this spectral sequence is only non-trivial along the diagonal boundary. This is nice - because we can see $D_v$ and higher differentials will never point along this diagonal so our spectral sequence has already collapsed.
If the double complex was bounded, we could relate our desired cohomology $H_D (X^n)$ to the total cohomology of our double complex. Can we say anything along those lines in the case given here? Does unboundedness completely destroy the relationship between the two, or are there additional conditions (perhaps involving our 'diagonal boundedness') we can check that may allow us to recover things?
